# pug include file structure explanation

Tags: pug

How do I solve the following issue. I have the following structure:

```
header
main
 .section-about
 .section-features
 .section-tours
 .section-stories
 .section-book
footer
```

In my index.pug I extend a general layout.pug file and then include the different partials.
This is the code to my index.pug:

```
extends layout-blocks/layout.pug
block append head
  title #{title} Home
  meta(name='description', content="Something " +addedDescription)
  meta(property='og:title', content= title +"Something

block content
  include layout-blocks/header.pug
  include layout-blocks/section-about.pug
```

And this is the code to the section-about.pug:

```
main
  section.section-about
    .u-center-text.u-margin-bottom-big
      h2.heading-secondary
        | Exciting tours for adventurous people
```

and so on..

This begins and closes the main tag and creates the .section-about within it, but how do I code the rest of the partials so they are embedded within the main tag, and the last partial closes the main tag?

I tried to see if I maybe could create a mixing for the structure, but not sure how to implement it in my solution.

This is the Mixins code:

```
mixin main
    main
        .section-about
        .section-features
        .section-tours
        .section-stories
        .section-book
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place to do this is in your layout.pug file. You can place the `block content` declaration within the `main` element.

**layout.pug:**

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')  
    head
        block head
    body
        header
            block header
        main
            block main
        footer
            block footer
```

**index.pug:**

```
extends layout.pug
    block append head
        title #{title} Home
        meta(name='description', content="Something " +addedDescription)
        meta(property='og:title', content= title +"Something

    block append header
        include header.pug

    block append main
        include section-about.pug
        include section-features.pug
        include section-tours.pug
        include section-stories.pug
        include section-book.pug

    block append footer
        include footer.pug
```

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely try out your suggestion, but is there a way to use the mixin i created and call it in my layout.pug file on the main portion?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trying to use a mixin for that. Normally mixins are used for chunks of code that repeat with minor variations.